# Call to a member function getValue() on a non-object in /var/www/docs/Project.com/public/application/controllers/ClientController.php on line 31

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-db

I am trying to insert a data into database and display it in grid but getting an error Call to a member function get Value() on a non-object.

Here is my controller code.

```
public function addAction()
{
$form = new Application_Form_user();
$form->submit->setlabel('add');
$this->view->form = $form;

if($this->getRequest()->isPost())
{

    $formData= $this->getRequest()->getPost();

    if($form->isvalid($formData))

        $client= new Application_Model_DbTable_Client();

    $firstname = $formData->getValue('firstname');
            $lastname = $formData->getValue('lastname');
            $email = $formData->getValue('email');

         echo"<pre>";
             print_r($fisrtname);die;   
             $client->addClient($firstname,$lastname,$email);

             $this->_helper->redirector('index');
     }

}
```

My model code.

```
public function addClient($firstname,$lastname,$email)
{

  $data=array('fisrtname'=>$firstname,
              'lastname'=>$lastname,
               'email'=>$email);
  $this->insert($data); 
}
```

Here is my user form code.

```
class Application_Form_user extends Zend_Form
{
  public function init()
{
    $id = new Zend_Form_Element_Hidden('id');
    $id->addFilter('Int');

    $firstname = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('firstname');
    $firstname->setlabel('firstname');
    $firstname->setRequired('true');


    $lastname = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('lastname');
    $lastname->setlabel('lastname');
    $lastname->setRequired('true');

    $email = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('email');
    $email->setlabel('email');
    $email->setRequired('true');

    $submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('submit');
    $submit->setlabel('submit');
    $submit->setRequired('true');


    $this->addElements(array($id, $firstname, $lastname, $email, $submit));
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$formData  = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
if($form->isvalid($formData))
   $client = new Application_Model_DbTable_Client();
$firstname = $formData['firstname'];
$lastname  = $formData['lastname'];
$email     = $formData['email'];
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply,I tried it but still data is not entering into database form disappears after I click on add button.

Answer (score 0):

sorry I made a spelling mistake in index name there it should be firstname rather than fisrtname.